# How to reorganise a table basis a criteria

Tags: vba

1. I have a table where columns exist at different rows as shown in Problem figure.
2. I am able to identify the rows of column headers (Numbered 1 in column A) and there values(Numbered 2,3 onwards in Column A).
3. I want collate it in a neat table as shown in Solution table; where all Column headers are in one row and subsequently we have their values.

Problem and expected results are as shown in picture
[image]

Comment: A belated welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55688451/edit) to include more information.  For example, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Use the [`Consolidate` wizard](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/consolidate-data-in-multiple-worksheets-007ce8f4-2fae-4fea-9ee5-a0b2c9e36d9b). Do tick "Top row", do not tick "Left column".